# Multithreaded web scraper—what's a typical concurrent limit?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm building a script that scrapes a website for some information. I expect to be making around 10k GET requests, and I'm speeding it up using multithreading. Something like this:

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=N) as pool:
    pool.map(requests.get, urls)
```

While I want my script to be fast, at the same time I want to be nice to the website's servers (and not be mistaken for a DOS attempt). While I found plenty of questions about how to multithread requests, I couldn't find any on a typical rate for making requests.

In this situation, what's a typical limit for the number of concurrent requests (`max_workers`)?

Comment: The relevant RFC ( https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html ) says not to use more than 2.

Comment: @IanMcLaird RFC2616 was written in 1999, so I'm not sure how much weight that guideline holds today.

Comment: You are correct.  And the RFC seems to have been revised.  This related question asks what limits are used by browsers, which might be useful to you as a starting point.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Comment: @IanMcLaird Thank you! That is definitely useful.